# Implementing a model of electro-diffusion

Tags: differential-equations, modeling

I am an undergraduate researcher. I have been working with Mathematica for roughly a month. I have been assigned a modeling task. My objective is to model the diffusion of ions in solution under the effect of an electric field and ignoring concentration gradient.

#### Model

The model is to be one dimensional for the time being. In the future it will be translated to 2D and ultimately 3D.

The equation used is as follows.

$\qquad $∂C/∂t = ∂/∂x(D ∂C/∂x - z μ C ∂Φ/∂x)

Where:

C : Concentration of ions

D: Diffusion coefficient

z: Charge per molecule

μ: Ion mobillity

Φ: Electric potential

C is a function of time and space, t and x.

Φ is a function of space, x.

All remaining terms are assumed to be constant. (D, z, μ)

The model I am making ignores diffusion caused by concentration gradient (The highlighted term).

∂C/∂t = ∂/∂x(**D ∂C/∂x** - z μ C ∂Φ/∂x)

The following assumptions are made.

D ∂C/∂x = 0

z = -1

μ = 1

This leaves us with:

∂C/∂t = ∂/∂x(C ∂Φ/∂x)

Finally, performing the product rule gives the final equation.

∂C/∂t = C (∂^2 Φ)/(∂x^2 ) + ∂C/∂x  ∂Φ/∂x

#### Code

`DSolve` presents a general solution. But despite multiple attempts and combinations of boundary and initial conditions of both the concentration and potential, I can’t get `DSolve` to present a particular solution. The code is as follows:

h1D Electrodiffusion

The purpose of this program is to model the diffusion of ions under the influence of an electric field only.

The first implementation will use `DSolve`. Later work will use `NDSolve` if no prior attempt was successful

The following describes the partial differential equation to be solved

```
edeqn = D[u[t, x], t] == u[t, x]*D[Φ[x], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x], x]*D[Φ[x], x]
```

The following attempts to solve the differential equation.

```
sol = DSolve[edeqn, u, {t, x}]
Simplify[edeqn /. sol]
```

This returns the general solution. I have provided a few sample of my attempts to attain a particular solution below.

The following shows the effect of adding an initial condition and a boundary condition for the left and right sides of the channel.

```
bc = {u[t, 0] == 10, u[t, 2] == 0}
ic = u[0, x] == 8
sol = DSolve[{edeqn, bc, ic}, u, {t, x}]
```

The following attempts to discern a solution to the differential equation. The solver has been told to solve for `u` and `Φ`. Both `u` and `Φ` are given as functions of `t` and `x`.

```
edeqn = 
  D[u[t, x], t] == u[t, x]*D[Φ[t, x], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x], x]*D[Φ[t, x], x]
sol = DSolve[edeqn, {u, Φ}, {t, x}]
```

Boundary condition. "u". Left side.
Boundary condition. "u". Right side.
Initial condition. "u".
Boundary condition "Φ". Left side.
Boundary condition "Φ". Right side.
Initial condition. "Φ".

```
bc = 
  {u[t, 0] == 10, u[t, 2] == 0, Φ[t, 0] == 5, Φ[t, 2] == 0}
ic = {u[0, x] == 8, Φ[0, x] == 0}
edeqn = 
  D[u[t, x], t] == u[t, x]*D[Φ[t, x], {x, 2}] + D[u[t, x], x]*D[Φ[t, x], x]
sol = DSolve[{edeqn, bc, ic}, {u, Φ}, {t, x}]
```

I apologize for the length of the post. I've never used a forum before.

I do hope you all will consider my dilemma, and are willing and able to provide a solution. I can show the full code of my attempts if necessary.

Comment: If $\phi$ is not given, then you need an equation for it. But I assume that $\phi$ is given in some way.

Comment: @user21 It was as you said. I had failed to specify ϕ in the code. After giving ϕ a value of a function with only "x", the solver worked just fine. Thank you for your answer, and thank you 'm_goldberg' for editing the post. Much of the work you two have done on StackExchange is the only reason I've gotten this far. It is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Thanks. @m_goldberg, pinging else you will not see the appreciation you got ;-). Other than that should we close the question as it's not going to get an  answer, Or Kali are you going to put something there?

Comment: Nope. I have another question, but it's probably better suited for a different post. I don't know think I have the ability to close the question. At your leisure, would one of you mind doing it?